# while else statement? PHP

Tags: php

So I have a validation in null values using while statement the code is

```
while (!$rs->EOF){ 
    echo "<tr><td>".$rs->Fields("Branch")."</td>";
    $rs->movenext();
}
$rs->Close();   

?>
```

What I wanted to achieve is to have an "else" statement though I know its not possible using the where statement. Which one is equivalent of it in where statement?

```
while (!$rs->EOF){ 
    echo "<tr><td>".$rs->Fields("Branch")."</td>";
    $rs->movenext();
}
if(!$rs->EOF)
{
    echo "<tr><td> Branch is missing</td>";
}
$rs->Close();   

?>
```

I tried using "if" I didn't get any errors though it didn't print what I wanted to print

Comment: *When* do you want to trigger this `else` condition? Currently it and your `while` condition are identical, doesn't make much sense. Please describe the logic in words.

Comment: where is `where statement`?

Comment: Where is the `where` statement above?

Comment: what i wanted to do is if the value of $rs is null it will print the "branch is missing" rather than printing nothing.

Comment: its while not where sorry guys blame the cofee ^_^

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While-Else does not exists in php.

You could use:

```
if ($rs->EOF) {
    echo "<tr><td> Branch is missing</td>";
} else {
    while (!$rs->EOF){ 
        echo "<tr><td>".$rs->Fields("Branch")."</td>";
        $rs->movenext();
    }
}
$rs->Close();
```

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest a slightly different way to approach this, it makes a bit more sense in my head:

```
if (!$rs.EOF()) {
    while (!$rs.EOF()) {
        // code...
    }
}
else {
    // code...
}
```

I think it makes more sense to me, because you generally want your expected outcome be handled within the if block, and the other outcome(s) to be handled in the else block.

Answer (score 0):

`while (!$rs->EOF){`  means "carry on doing this until `$rs->EOF` is `true`". When it ends, `$rs-EOF` will always be true (otherwise the loop wouldn't have ended), so the conditional will never pass.

You need to do a test at some point (possibly *before* the `while` loop) to see if there are any results found. Without knowing what library you are using, it's impossible to say how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You should check that the result-set is not empty *before* attempting to loop through it.

E.g. something like this pseudo-code:

```
rs = sql("SELECT ...");

if (rs.isEmpty())
    print "No data";
else
{
    while (!rs.EOF())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think below code would help you,

```
<?php while (!$rs->EOF){ 

     if($rs->Fields("Branch"))
     {
      echo "<tr><td>".$rs->Fields("Branch")."</td>";
     $rs->movenext();
     }else{
      echo "<tr><td> Branch is missing</td>";
     }
}

$rs->Close();   

?>
```