# While-Else Condition PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, while-loop

I know that my question might be similar with
[while else statement? PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951708/while-else-statement-php).
However, that solution doesn't seem to work with my case.

> So, in my case is something like this.

1. I do the `select` query from database to get all records then get the `result in array`
2. I get the `total` and `period` from the array
3. Do the checking, when the `$qtyOut > $total`, it will loop the statements inside the `{}`.
4. This is the problem here, AFTER LOOP ENDS, it should do else statement (call another function).

```
    public function trialOut($id, $qtyOut)
        {
            $a = $this->uri->segment(3);
            $dataset = $this->m1->trial($a);
            $i = 0;
            $sisa;
            $total = $dataset[$i]['total'];
            $period = $dataset[$i]['periode'];
            if($qtyOut > $total){
                while ($qtyOut > $total) {
                    $qtyOut = $qtyOut - $total;
                    $this->m1->updateOut2($period, $id);
                    $i++;
                    $total = $dataset[$i]['total'];
                    $period = $dataset[$i]['periode'];
                }
            } else{ //when while loop ends, i want it to execute the code here
                $sisa = $total - $qtyOut;
                $this->m1->updateOut1($period, $sisa, $id);
            }
        }
```

And I still can't found the proper way to do this, should I use another loop method and how to do that?

Comment: why do you need the `if/else` in this case? What could go wrong with just having the `while` loop, and then the code in your current `else` block after (and outside) the loop, to always execute after the loop has finished?

Comment: the statements inside `else` condition, will be executed if only the `$qtyOut` is not larger than `$total`.
cmiiw

Comment: but you said you wanted them to occur after the `while` loop finishes - which means you also want those statements executed if `$qtyOut > $total` (just after the loop, in that case). [I haven't actually really looked at your code and its intention yet, btw - I'm just trying to follow the logic of what you're asking for.]

Comment: well then, you're right bro. I have the misconception about `while` statement.
it's been a help, thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If - else statement is working by this logic. if condition under if statement is true code insde {} `if(condition) {//this code is executed}` will execute. However if **condition = false** code under else will execute. Having that in mind your else statement WILL NOT execute when `$qtyOut > $total` .

If you want to execute it after if statement just remove else and brackets.

If you want to execute it after while ends try this

```
public function trialOut($id, $qtyOut)
        {
            $a = $this->uri->segment(3);
            $dataset = $this->m1->trial($a);
            $i = 0;
            $sisa;
            $total = $dataset[$i]['total'];
            $period = $dataset[$i]['periode'];
            if($qtyOut > $total){
                while ($qtyOut > $total) {
                    $qtyOut = $qtyOut - $total;
                    $this->m1->updateOut2($period, $id);
                    $i++;
                    $total = $dataset[$i]['total'];
                    $period = $dataset[$i]['periode'];
                }
                $sisa = $total - $qtyOut;
                $this->m1->updateOut1($period, $sisa, $id);
            } 
        }
```

> If else explanation

Take this example

```
x = 5;
if( x = 5 ){
echo 'x is 5';
}
if( x != 5){
echo 'x is not five'
}
```

is the same code as

```
x = 5;
if( x = 5 ){
echo 'x is 5';
}else{
echo 'x is not five'
}
```

In first case you are checking if x = 5 and then if x is not equal to 5.
In second case you are checking if x = 5 and if it isn't only then else will execute